# Electron - jQuery Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I'm working on an Electron project, and when attempting to include jQuery, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Electron\ElectronProjects\Iris\js\jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught SyntaxError:
C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Electron\ElectronProjects\Iris\js\jquery.min.js:4 b),b&&a.jQuery===n&&(a.jQuery=Hb),n},b||(a.jQuery=a.$=n),n});jQuery v3.0.0-pre
```

I'v attempted to use the way that was recommended in the Electron issues page (window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./../js/jquery.min.js');). It always throws this error though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require(__dirname+'/js/jquery.js');
</script>
```

I used this for jquery 1.9.1 version its works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like adding `"node-integration": false` to my BrowserWindow constructor fixed it. I'd still like an explanation why I have to do so though :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer "why", according to this post:  https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/254

"jQuery contains...

```
if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) 
{
  // set jQuery in `module`
} 
else
{
  // set jQuery in `window`
}
```

module is defined, even in the browser-side scripts. This causes jQuery to ignore the window object and use module, so the other scripts won't find $ nor jQuery in global scope.."